# Sympy Cross and dot products without evaluating

Tags: python, sympy

Looking in the Documentantion of the [vector package](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/api/classes.html) I did not find any way to take the cross/dot product of two vectors without evaluating the expression, e.g. without simplify the recurring terms in the result of the operation. Is this possible?

Comment: It has been added to the master branch a few weeks ago. You'd need the latest development branch.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you create an answer to the question (possibly with a link) so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have the latest development version:

In the vector module there are the `dot` and `cross` functions that calculate the dot and cross products, and the classes `Dot` and `Cross` that create an unevaluated expression representing the same products.

Import the vector module and SymPy:

```
In [1]: from sympy import *; from sympy.vector import *
```

Define a coordinate system:

```
In [2]: C = CoordSys3D("C")
```

At this point, `C.i, C.j, C.k` are the base vectors.

Cross product with immediate evaluation (lowercase `cross`):

```
In [3]: cross(C.i, C.j)
Out[3]: C.k
```

Let's use a nice printer to print the cross product as an operator:

```
In [4]: init_printing()
```

Cross product in unevaluated form (name with capital *C* letter `Cross`):

```
In [5]: Cross(C.i, C.j)
Out[5]: (C_i)×(C_j)
```

To perform the calculation, just use `.doit()`:

```
In [6]: Cross(C.i, C.j).doit()
Out[6]: C_k
```

Comment: Where can I find the reference to this new feature?

Comment: @falematte it is still undocumented, you have to go to Sympy source code -> vector -> vector.py